# Biggest of Five

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have problem with one simple task:

> *"Write a program that finds the biggest of 5 numbers that are read from the console, using only 5 if statements:"*
>
> **Input:**
>
> On the first 5 lines you will receive the 5 numbers, each on a
>   separate line
>
> **Output:**
>
> On the only output line, write the biggest of the 5 numbers
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> The 5 numbers will always be valid floating-point numbers in the range
>   [-200, 200]
>
> **Time limit:** 0.1s
>
> **Memory limit:** 16MB

My solution is:

```
if (
            firstNum < -200 && firstNum > 200 ||
                    secondNum < -200 && secondNum > 200 ||
                    thirdNum < -200 && thirdNum > 200 ||
                    forthNum < -200 && forthNum > 200 ||
                    fifthNum < -200 && fifthNum > 200) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Number");
    } else {
        double max = Math.max(firstNum, Math.max(secondNum, Math.max(thirdNum, Math.max(forthNum, fifthNum))));
        if (max == (int) max) {
        System.out.println((int) max);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(max);
        }

    }
}
```

}

This work correct, but the problems are in time limit:

> Test case #1: TLE [>0.100s,   41.15 MB]   (0/0)

***Time Limit Exceeded**

Regards
N.M.

Answer (score 2):

Keep your code simple and stick to the given conditions.

```
 //Init max =-201 so that it is as minimum as possible.
 double max= -201;
 if(firstNum>max){
    max=firstNum;
 }
 if(secondNum>max){
    max=secondNum;
 }
 if(thirdNum>max){
    max=thirdNum;
 }
 if(forthNum>max){
    max=forthNum;
 }
 if(fifthNum>max){
    max=fifthNum;
 }
 System.out.println(max);
```

Comment: @НиколайМатев You can accept the answer if you found it useful

Answer (score 0):

Initialize maximum so far to some small value (anything below -200 will do). Then when you read the numbers one by one, check the number you just read whether it is larger than the maximum so far and set the maximum so far to it if it is. After you have read 5 numbers, output the maximum so far.
This can be done in a nice loop, there is no need to store the five numbers in separate variables.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is a time limit, the cause is not apparent from the code you posted.  All of that should execute in a couple of milliseconds.

The most likely explanation for your running into the 1/10th of a second time limit is that something in causing your JVM to start slowly.

- One possibility is there is some other "cruft" in your application that is causing this.  (Please show us your complete application: and MCVE, in fact.)
- A second possibility is that you have an infinite loop in some other part of your code that you are not showing us; e.g. your code for reading the 5 numbers.
- Another possibility is that there is something odd about your Java installation.  For example, if it was installed on a remote network share, then that would impact on JVM startup times.

---

**UPDATE**

I compiled and ran your code and my conclusion is that this is all down to JVM startup times.

```
$ time java BiggestOfFiveMaxMath01  < /tmp/in
5

real    0m0.119s
user    0m0.125s
sys 0m0.018s
```

You are unlikely to be able to improve on this unless you rewrite it in a language like C or C++ which can be compiled to native code ahead of time.